# How to check the integrity of the sqlite database?

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

I use [`sqlite_orm`](https://github.com/fnc12/sqlite_orm/) to create\read\write\update\**backup**\**restore** the sqlite database on embedded systems which runs `Ubuntu 16.04`.

Since the embedded system may be suddenly powered off(which is out of my control. see the note) and the application may be seldomly & unexpected  killed or crashed, how can I check the integrity of the sqlite database by `sqlite_orm` when the application starts?

If this goal could not be achieved by `sqlite_orm`, then how to do it by the ***C APIs*** provided in the library of `sqlite`?

**Update**:

NOTE: The hardware has no UPS or emergency power supply.All what I can do is to backup the database in time and check the integrity when the application starts.

Comment: [PRAGMA integrity_check](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check)

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Thanks, but `PRAGMA schema.integrity_check` seems not to be a C API.

Comment: No, it's a SQL command. Presumably you can execute SQL statements against the database using the C API's ??

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Sorry for my poor English. Maybe I don't fully understand you. As far as I see, I can access\update the `sqlite` database by C APIs(e.g. `sqlite3_exec()` and `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` which could be seen in the implementation of `sqlite_orm`, and I also could directly call them too).

Comment: Okay, if by that you mean that you don't know how to use the C API, then you should read [An Introduction to the SQLite C Interface](https://sqlite.org/cintro.html)

Comment: Why would turning off a device or killing the application corrupt the database?

Comment: @AnonCoward It's out of my control. At least, the hardware has no `UPS` or emergency power supply.All what I can do is to backup the database in time and check the integrity when the application starts.